# Slow array declaration in Xcode6

Tags: arrays, performance, swift

In a swift test app I´m using an array with 38 elements. See below.
When compiling the app it does not complete and gets stuck at step 2.
When using less than 20 elements it´s working normal.

Any idea what´s wrong?

```
    var legacyArray:NSArray = [
        ["usage":"eBay G", "name":"prologrmh", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"Tipp24", "name":"Gargantua20", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"DynDNS.com ", "name":"Gargantua20", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"privat", "name":"gronnymaus", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"macgadget.de", "name":"Pantagruel", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"youTube.com", "name":"Pantagruel20", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"Adobe", "name":"prolog@jumbosoft.de", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"DHL myAT", "name":"prolog@jumbosoft.de", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"Openbase", "name":"prolog@jumbosoft.de", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"PayPal", "name":"prolog@jumbosoft.de", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"Quoka", "name":"prolog@jumbosoft.de", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"tvtv", "name":"RonaldHofmann", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"TVInfo", "name":"Pantagruel20", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"ronnyonthur", "name":"romy@jumbosoft.de", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"DynDNS", "name":"RonaldMHofmann", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"skype", "name":"ronny0944", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"stayfriends", "name":"ronny@jumbosoft.de", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"lotto-bw.de(2080763878)", "name":"ronnyka", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"t-com", "name":"ronnyka", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"trinity.NeoOffice", "name":"ronnyka", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"Atrada", "name":"ronnymta", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"eBay P", "name":"ronnymta", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"Logitech Harmony 525", "name":"ronnymta", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"MacNews", "name":"ronnymta", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"MacOSX Hints", "name":"ronnymta", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"privat", "name":"ronnymta", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"quoka", "name":"ronnymta", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"www.cgi2you.com", "name":"ronnymta", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"digitalfernsehen", "name":"ronnymta ", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"Jabber", "name":"ronnymta@macme.de", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"skype", "name":"ronnyOh", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"g4clr", "name":"taubenchat.de", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"NJT0O", "name":"DSP", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"digitec", "name":"Gargantua20", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"Webmail", "name":"prolog@jumbosoft.de", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"ftpjum34888", "name":"prolog@jumbosoft.de", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"Apfeltalk", "name":"Pantagruel", "pass":"aPassword"],
        ["usage":"MacWelt", "name":"Pantagruel", "pass":"aPassword"]
    ]
```

Comment: Send a bug report to Apple. I cannot see an error in your code, so we probably cannot help here.

Comment: I hope these aren't actual email addresses ...